# Quickbox iOS Content API -- how to tag content

Tags: ios, quickblox

I notice that there are you can query object with tags.

But how do I get tags associated with the objects in the first place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By adding tag to Content File you say that users with this tag will be able to retrieve this file with query

```
[QBContent taggedBlobsWithPagedRequest:pagedRequest delegate:self];
```

To update user's tags use

```
QBUUser *user = [QBUUser user];
user.tags = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"man", @"travel", nil];
[QBUsers updateUser:user delegate:self];
```

Comment: I want to associate a profile picture with each user, is this what I should use? What is QBUUser's blobID for?

Comment: I'm sorry. Could you elaborate because I am not entirely clear. Do you mean when I want to associate a profile picture (content) with each user, I would use blobID but not tag? How do I use blob ID?

Comment: here is a good example http://quickblox.com/developers/SimpleSample-users-ios#Update_profile_picture_.28avatar.29

Comment: Nice example, thanks. I noticed that blobID is obtained from uploading the picture and there is only one blobID field per user. So in addition to avatar if I want to associate multiple images or other type of resources such as sound clips, etc, would I use tags and let all tags be unique?